# How can I change gui wallet display locale/language

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, language

It switched from English to Dutch

Comment: figured it out..  when starting monero-wallet-gui, cancel where it ask for wallet password and you can select the language and regional format.

selected english, then restart monero-wallet-gui and login.

Comment: since you figured it out, please go ahead and post an answer to your own question, rather than just leaving a comment

Answer (score 1):

When starting monero-wallet-gui, cancel where it ask for wallet password and you can select the language and regional format. selected english, then restart monero-wallet-gui and login.